# SQL Query Joining Tables, Getting Duplicate

Tags: sql, left-join

So I am trying to join multiple tables here. I need to grab a few columns from my last table to make the query complete. Although, when I do a join on this last table I end up getting multiple rows. The top return is after the join, the bottom is before.
[image]

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT 
prh_nbr as 'PO', 
ad_name as 'Supplier', 
pt_part as 'Part Number', 
pt_desc1 as 'Part Description', 
prh_rcvd as 'Qty Received', 
CAST(prh_qty_ord as int) as 'Quantity Ordered', 
prh_pur_cost as 'Purchase Cost', 
(prh_pur_cost * prh_rcvd) as 'Total Cost', 
CAST(e.prh_rcp_date As Date) As 'Date Received' 
    from qad_repl.dbo.pod_det_sql as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.po_mstr_sql as b ON (a.pod_nbr = b.po_nbr)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.ad_mstr_sql as c ON (b.po_vend = c.ad_addr)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.pt_mstr_sql as d ON (a.pod_part = d.pt_part)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.prh_hist_sql as e ON (po_nbr = e.prh_nbr)
    where pt_part is not null and po_nbr is not null and pod_qty_rcvd > 0
    and prh_nbr = 'PO1701' and prh_rcp_date >= '2015-01-21' and prh_rcp_date <= '2015-01-22'
```

And then for the second one:

```
SELECT 
pod_nbr as 'PO', 
ad_name as 'Supplier', 
pt_part as 'Part Number', 
pt_desc1 as 'Part Description'
       from qad_repl.dbo.pod_det_sql as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.po_mstr_sql as b ON (a.pod_nbr = b.po_nbr)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.ad_mstr_sql as c ON (b.po_vend = c.ad_addr)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.pt_mstr_sql as d ON (a.pod_part = d.pt_part)
    where pt_part is not null and po_nbr is not null and pod_qty_rcvd > 0
    and pod_nbr = 'PO1701'
```

I am not sure how much information you will need/want to see, but I am trying to keep this as clean as possible.

When trying to join my last table (prh_hist_sql) seems that I can only join on PO Number and Line Number.. In the example above I did po_nbr, which is why I am getting the four rows instead of two... If I do line number I will get a bunch more, as shown in this picture..

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas to help me out?
I can display more information if needed, just ask.

Comment: Do you want to do a UNION ALL? (Add null's to the shorter select list.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a single date received...do you just want to get the most recent prh_hist_date (received date) from the prh_hist_sql (history) table in the result set you are currently returning?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how a UNION ALL would work.. I am playing around with it right now to see if I can make it work @jarlh

Comment: @Madison If by current result set you mean the query with only two rows, basically yes... I need to have qty received, qty ordered, purchase cost, total cost and the date received added to my current result set

Comment: @KyleRickaby it would help if in your query you specified which tables you drew each selected field from like a.phr_nbr for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, join on PO AND Line... Then Distinct it! :D

```
SELECT DISTINCT pod_nbr as 'PO', ad_name as 'Supplier', pt_part as 'Part Number', pt_desc1 as 'Part Description'
   from qad_repl.dbo.pod_det_sql as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.po_mstr_sql as b ON (a.pod_nbr = b.po_nbr)
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.ad_mstr_sql as c ON (b.po_vend = c.ad_addr)
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.pt_mstr_sql as d ON (a.pod_part = d.pt_part)
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.prh_hist_sql as e ON (po_nbr = e.prh_nbr and pod_line = e.prh_line)
where pt_part is not null and po_nbr is not null and pod_qty_rcvd > 0
and pod_nbr = 'PO1701'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
SELECT prh_nbr as 'PO', ad_name as 'Supplier', pt_part as 'Part Number', pt_desc1 as 'Part Description', prh_rcvd as 'Qty Received', 
CAST(prh_qty_ord as int) as 'Quantity Ordered', prh_pur_cost as 'Purchase Cost'
    , (prh_pur_cost * prh_rcvd) as 'Total Cost'
    , (select max(prh_rcp_date) from prh_hist_sql where prh_nbr = b.po_nbr and prh_rcp_date >= '2015-01-21' and prh_rcp_date <= '2015-01-22') 'Date Received' 
from qad_repl.dbo.pod_det_sql as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.po_mstr_sql as b ON (a.pod_nbr = b.po_nbr)
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.ad_mstr_sql as c ON (b.po_vend = c.ad_addr)
LEFT OUTER JOIN qad_repl.dbo.pt_mstr_sql as d ON (a.pod_part = d.pt_part)
where pt_part is not null and po_nbr is not null and pod_qty_rcvd > 0
    and prh_nbr = 'PO1701' 
    and exists(select 1 from prh_hist_sql where prh_nbr = b.po_nbr and prh_rcp_date >= '2015-01-21' and prh_rcp_date <= '2015-01-22')
```

Instead of joining on the history table, use subqueries to specifiy criteria and aggregate the field you want (Date Received)

Comment: It doesn't like that, It doesn't have a way to tell what prh_nbr is in the first select.... Nice Picture of Carol by your name though!!! :D